# Angular2 and Redux : get state in a component

Tags: angular, redux

I need to get access to a state inside a Component. Most of the examples show how to consume the state inside the template, using @select and async pipe but not directly in a Component. The needed state is not supposed to change in the time.

I see 3 solutions :

**1/ Use getState()**

```
constructor(private ngRedux: NgRedux) { }
ngOnInit() {
    this.prop = this.ngRedux.getState().prop;
    // Do what I need with "this.prop"
}
```

**2/ Move this getter into a Action Creator Service**

```
getProp() {
    return this.ngRedux.getState().prop;
}
```

**3/ Subscribe to the @select() property**

```
@select('stateProp') stateProp$;
property: string;
constructor(private ngRedux: NgRedux) { }
ngOnInit() {
    stateProp$.subscribe(state => this.property = state)
    // Do what I need with "this.property"
}
```

What's the best way to perform that ?

Thx

Answer (score 3):

There's probably no right or wrong answer to this, but having just added Redux to an Angular app, here's my thoughts.

`ngRedux.getState()` returns a snapshot, whereas `@select()` sets up a pipeline that responds every time the state fragment changes.

One of the major reasons for using Redux is to reduce complexity with **shared** state, in which case we want to use `@select` in order to respond to changes caused by other components.

Example 3 above is problematic.
Firstly, we can't be sure that the subscription will complete before the rest of the `ngOnInit()` code executes, so `this.property` may be uninitialized when we don't expect it to be.

Secondly, do we want a snapshot, in which case use `getState()`, or do we want a pipeline, in which case move the subsequent code inside the subscribe:

```
@select('stateProp') stateProp$;
property: string;

constructor(private ngRedux: NgRedux) { }

ngOnInit() {
  stateProp$.subscribe(state => {
    this.property = state;
    // Do what I need with "this.property"
  })
}
```

The same might be said when we use `this.property` in other methods.
Seems to me `this.property` and `stateProp$` refer to the same state, so have one or the other but not both.

Aside from constraining the shape of the code, I've found `@select()` to have some other problems.

**Pipeline executes before state is initialized.**
Depending on how state is initialized, we may receive an `undefined` value through the pipeline, e.g

```
export interface IAppState {
  config?: any;
}

export const initialState: IAppState = {}

@select() config$: any;

ngOnInit() {
  config$.subscribe(config => {
    this.color = config.color;  // Error: Cannot read property 'color' of undefined
                                // May happen if config is obtained async
  }
}
```

A guard can be used:

```
ngOnInit() {
  config$
    .filter(data => !!data)
    .subscribe(config => {
      this.color = config.color;
  }
}
```

or make sure initialState initializes all object levels:

```
export const initialState: IAppState = { config: {} }
```

**Pipeline continuously executes**
If you need to look at existing state before updating it, the subscription will continuously fire. Note, the connection between subscription and dispatch might be subtle (sub-state change, or separation by nested methods):

```
@select() myDataList$: IDataArray;

myMethod() {
  this.myDataList$.subscribe(myDataList => {
    // Check something on myDataList
    console.log('I will continuously loop');
    this.addDataMethod();
  }
}
addDataMethod() {
  ngRedux.dispatch({type: addSomeDataAction, payload: myData});
}
```

Using `ngRedux.getState()` would be the preferred access method, or limit the subscription with `.take(1)`.

**Cleaning up subscriptions**
Subscriptions in Angular currently need to be unsubscribed in `ngOnDestroy()` if not completed with a `.take(n)` or similar operator. Without this step, the subscription continues after the component is gone.
Ref: [Angular/RxJs When should I unsubscribe from `Subscription`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription)

```
@select() myData$: IMyData;
private myDataSub;

myMethod() {
  this.myDataSub = this.myData$.subscribe(myData => {
    // Do something with myData
  }
}
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.myDataSub.unsubscribe();
}
```